# How to get escaped file description from node?

Tags: entities, theming

I enabled file description for node and I want to display descriptions close to the download links.
I would like the description be secure. I tried

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_files');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo $item['description'];
}
```

but there is html code parsed.

I can use just `check_plain()` function on the description, but is there any way to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [comments to official documentation](http://api.drupal.org/comment/23698#comment-23698):

> It is worth noting that [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) returns raw values the use of which can be a security risk. Passing the raw values through [field_view_value()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) handles the sanitizing of the values.

Links added by me.

Comment: OK, looks promising, but it gives me a link if I use `render()` to it and insecure value if I use `echo $value['#file']->description`

Comment: You are passing whole item to field_view_value(), right? can you `dpr()` it's result? For `$display` settings, see [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) - you need to set proper formatter, I guess you want something like `'text_summary_or_trimmed'`. Or just use check_plain and don't bother ;)